# sqlalchemy: how to join several tables by one query?

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy mapped classes:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    email = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = "documents"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    author = Column(String, ForeignKey("users.email"))

class DocumentsPermissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "documents_permissions"
    readAllowed = Column(Boolean)
    writeAllowed = Column(Boolean)

    document = Column(String, ForeignKey("documents.name"))
```

I need to get a table like this for `user.email = "user@email.com"`:

```
email | name | document_name | document_readAllowed | document_writeAllowed
```

How can it be made using one query request for SQLAlchemy? The code below does not work for me:

```
result = session.query(User, Document, DocumentPermission).filter_by(email = "user@email.com").all()
```

Thanks,

Comment: I've found that the following works to join two tables: `result = session.query(User, Document).select_from(join(User, Document)).filter(User.email=='user@email.com').all()` But I have not managed yet how to make work the similar for three tables (to include DocumentPermissions). Any Idea?

Comment: When I perform similar task, I get SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Answer (score 144):

Try this

```
q = Session.query(
         User, Document, DocumentPermissions,
    ).filter(
         User.email == Document.author,
    ).filter(
         Document.name == DocumentPermissions.document,
    ).filter(
        User.email == 'someemail',
    ).all()
```

Comment: What kind of `join` does it do? inner, outer, cross or what?

Comment: This actually doesn't do a join at all, it returns row objects in a tuple. In this case, it'd return `[(<user>, <document>, <documentpermissions>),...]`/

Comment: "doesn't do a join at all" - that's a little misleading. It will have sql like `select x from a, b ,c` which is a cross join. The filters then make it an inner join.

Comment: You can print the query by leaving off the `.all()`.  So `print Session.query....` to see exactly what it is doing.

Comment: @FakeName  how to print the result from the returned tuple.

Comment: I am new to SQLAlchemy. I noticed `.filter()` can receive multiple criteria if comma separated.  Is it preferable to use one `.filter()` with comma separations inside the parenthesis, or use multiple `.filter()` like the above answer?

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer use a single `.filter` if you wish to join using the implicit `and_` SQLAlchemy filter qualifier (represents "where .. and .." in SQL). It is identical in SQL terms (unless I am mistaken) as tagging on a sequence of .filter functions to the overall expression.

Comment: Coming from a strong SQL background, this just bothers me.  When I see `filter`, I associate that with a `WHERE` clause, and within standard SQL you don't use `WHERE` to specify your joins.  The SQLAlchemy docs themselves also conflate the two.

Comment: @AidanKane `select x from a, b ,c` your comment is also a bit misleading, since there is no difference between a cross join and an inner join when using the where clause.

Answer (score 108):

As @letitbee said, its best practice to assign primary keys to tables and properly define the relationships to allow for proper ORM querying. That being said...

If you're interested in writing a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT
    user.email,
    user.name,
    document.name,
    documents_permissions.readAllowed,
    documents_permissions.writeAllowed
FROM
    user, document, documents_permissions
WHERE
    user.email = "user@email.com";
```

Then you should go for something like:

```
session.query(
    User, 
    Document, 
    DocumentsPermissions
).filter(
    User.email == Document.author
).filter(
    Document.name == DocumentsPermissions.document
).filter(
    User.email == "user@email.com"
).all()
```

---

If instead, you want to do something like:

```
SELECT 'all the columns'
FROM user
JOIN document ON document.author_id = user.id AND document.author == User.email
JOIN document_permissions ON document_permissions.document_id = document.id AND document_permissions.document = document.name
```

Then you should do something along the lines of:

```
session.query(
    User
).join(
    Document
).join(
    DocumentsPermissions
).filter(
    User.email == "user@email.com"
).all()
```

One note about that...

```
query.join(Address, User.id==Address.user_id) # explicit condition
query.join(User.addresses)                    # specify relationship from left to right
query.join(Address, User.addresses)           # same, with explicit target
query.join('addresses')                       # same, using a string
```

For more information, visit the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins).

Comment: DO THIS. See - not a lot of stuff specified in the joins. That's because if the tables/db-model has already been setup-up with proper foreign keys between these tables - SQLAlchemy will take care of joining ON the proper columns for you.

Comment: This is the most correct answer and proper use of sqlalchemy. However, I had to use the filter solution because SQLAlchemy does not accept delete statements with join()

Answer (score 65):

A good style would be to setup some relations and a primary key for permissions (actually, usually it is good style to setup **integer** primary keys for everything, but whatever):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    email = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Document(Base):
    __tablename__ = "documents"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    author_email = Column(String, ForeignKey("users.email"))
    author = relation(User, backref='documents')

class DocumentsPermissions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "documents_permissions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    readAllowed = Column(Boolean)
    writeAllowed = Column(Boolean)
    document_name = Column(String, ForeignKey("documents.name"))
    document = relation(Document, backref = 'permissions')
```

Then do a simple query with joins:

```
query = session.query(User, Document, DocumentsPermissions).join(Document).join(DocumentsPermissions)
```

Comment: What is `query` set to in the last line and how do you access the joined records in it?

Comment: @pate I'm not sure what you mean by 'what is query set to', but it will join according the relations, and the yield 3-tuples. The arguments to the query() call are essentially the select list in sqlalchemy.

Comment: How do I access the `Document` (2nd tuple value) in the query result set?

Comment: @PetrusTheron Like I said, query will yield 3-tuples. You can index elements, or just unpack: `for (user, doc, perm) in query: print "Document: %s" % doc`

Comment: what is `'permissions'` in `document = relation(Document, backref = 'permissions')` ?

Comment: Whoa, blast from the past. 'permissions' is an attribute of Document object, that gives you set of DocumentPermission objects. Hence backref.

Comment: is there a possibility to use the ORM-relations more effectively, so that additional join-terms do not have to be explicitly declared? i.e. `Document`, should already know how to join a user by its `author` attribute, so I would guess that `session.query(Document.name, Document.author.email)` should in principle be able to resolve; but to me it doesn't :(

Comment: @mzolI think there is now! Have not worked with sqlalchemy for a bit, but apparently in new versions you can do something like `session.query(Document).join(Document.author)`.  Looks a lot less derpy, I must admit. Source: https://www.pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-orm-examples/

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have to write `.join(Document)` and `.join(DocumentsPermissions)` but don't need to specify User with `.join(User)` or similar. What defines User to be the base of this query, that the other tables join to? Is it just that User is the first argument to `query()`? Does it need to be the FIRST argument if so?

Comment: @user2428107 Yes, and yes. It makes some degree of sense when you think of it -- the resulting sql query is `SELECT ... from users join documents join documents_permissions ...`

Comment: Thanks @letitbee. On further reading of docs it looks like there is a `.select_from()` function that can be used to specify what the base table for the query is, but it's optional and the default is the leftmost query argument. So if I understand correctly a `.select_from(User)` could have been chained into this call without in this case changing the result. Confusingly when I tried my own code I was able to change the order of query arguments without this and it still all worked! Maybe depending on the foreign key relationships, it is sometimes just unambiguous what the join ought to be.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding on Abdul's answer, you can obtain a [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) instead of a discrete collection of rows by joining the columns:

```
q = Session.query(*User.__table__.columns + Document.__table__.columns).\
        select_from(User).\
        join(Document, User.email == Document.author).\
        filter(User.email == 'someemail').all()
```

Comment: This works.  However, they column names are missing when serializing the object.

Answer (score 3):

This function will produce required table as list of tuples.

```
def get_documents_by_user_email(email):
    query = session.query(
       User.email, 
       User.name, 
       Document.name, 
       DocumentsPermissions.readAllowed, 
       DocumentsPermissions.writeAllowed,
    )
    join_query = query.join(Document).join(DocumentsPermissions)

    return join_query.filter(User.email == email).all()

user_docs = get_documents_by_user_email(email)
```