# Return query with columns from multiple tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I haven't been able to find an answer to this, but I'm sure it must be somewhere.
My question is similar to this question: [sqlalchemy: how to join several tables by one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044309/sqlalchemy-how-to-join-several-tables-by-one-query)

But I need a query result, not a tuple. I don't have access to the models, so I can't change it, and I can't modify the functions to use a tuple.

I have two tables, `UserInformation` and `MemberInformation`, both with a foreign key and relationship to `Principal`, but not to each other.

How can I get all the records and columns from both tables in one query?
I've tried:

```
query = DBSession.query(MemberInformation).join(UserInformation, MemberInformation.pId == UserInformation.pId)
```

but it only returns the columns of MemberInformation

and:

```
query = DBSession.query(MemberInformation, UserInformation).join(UserInformation, MemberInformation.pId == UserInformation.pId)
```

but that returns a tuple.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how do you want to see your query result? what about .all() - it'll return a list

Comment: I know, but I specifically need a query object. I perform further operations on it etc

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6045131/2372812 - you can put multiple tables in the `query()` part.

Comment: E.g. use `query(table1, table2).filter(table1.thing == table2.other_thing)`

Comment: That answer returns a tuple

Comment: q = session.query(MemberInformation, UserInformation).join(MemberInformation.pId)

Comment: Sorry that also returns a tuple

Answer (score 6):

Old question, but worth answering because i see it's got a lot of view activity.

You need to create a relationship and then tell SQLAlchemy how to load the related data. Not sure what your tables / relationship looks like, but it might look something like this:

```
# Create relationship
MemberInformation.user = relationship(
    "UserInformation",
    foreign_keys=[MemberInformation.pId],
    lazy="joined",
)

# Execute query
query = DBSession.query(MemberInformation) \
    .options(joinedload(MemberInformation.user)) \
    .all()

# All objects are in memory. Evaluating the following will NOT result in additional
# database interaction
for member in query:
    print(f'Member: {member} User: {member.user}')

# member is a MemberInformation object, member.user is a UserInformation object
```

Ideally, the relationship would be defined in your models. If can, however, be defined at run time list the example above.

Answer (score 5):

Only way I found to do this is to use statement instead of query:

```
stmt = select([table1, table2.col.label('table2_col')]).select_from(join(table1, table2, table1.t1_id == table2.t2_id))
obj = session.execute(stmt).fetchall()
```