# Flask sqlalchemy: joining tables of a distant relationship

Tags: python, flask, relationship

I'm trying to join a table with its children's children.
I have this relationship: store->department->employee where a store has many departments and each department has many employees. How can I make it such that I have a table with store and employee joined together? Can I achieve this in flask/sqlalchemy? (similar to this laravel "has many through" relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlalchemy: how to join several tables by one query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044309/sqlalchemy-how-to-join-several-tables-by-one-query)

Comment: that was one of the results that I saw. The second answer was:
query = session.query(User, Document, DocumentsPermissions).join(Document).join(DocumentsPermissions).all()
Now, what if I want all documentsPermissions for a user? 
Something like query.filter(User.id == 2).documentsPermission
where I want a user with id == 2 and fetch me all of his/her document permission regardless of where each document maps to each permission?