# How to join 2 tables from different queries in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have 2 queries which both get a subset of a tables, let's call them `Table1` and `Table2`
I would like to join these 2 child tables on their `id`.

I tried something like this, but it throws unhelpful errors:

```
table1: List[Table1] = db.session.execute(query1)
table2: List[Table2] = db.session.execute(query2)

db.session.query(table1).join(table2, table1.id == table2.id).all()
```

Comment: You shouldn't execute the queries before joining. You just join the queries and that will execute the join.

Comment: @Barmar I see, but then how do I specify that I want to join using the `id`?

Comment: You can't join raw queries like this. Remember, the join is implemented in the DB, not SQLAlchemy. If you're using raw queries, it doesn't know how to combine them.

Comment: If you want to join the DB, how about just joining directly like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045131/10118118 ?

Comment: Follow @Barmar's advice. But to _literally_ answer the original question, consider defining a pair of VIEWs, which some folks refer to as "named queries". Then it's very convenient to construct a JOIN of 1st view against 2nd view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the tables before executing the query.
Maybe you wanted to do like this?

```py
results = db.session.query(Table1).filter(
        {whatever the query1 does}, 
        {whatever the query2 does}
    ).join(Table2, Table1.id==Table2.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, combining the queries did the job. I also followed @J_H 's advice and used *view*s for conveniently storing my queries.